# Is there Armour/Barding for horses in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am completely new to Skyrim, I just started two days ago, anyways I recently bought a horse and the horse keeps dieing, I have to reload a previous save in order to keep my horse.

**So I am wondering if there is any kind of armour (also known as Barding) or any additional protection I can offer my horse?**

Comment: Sorry about the duplicate, I searched the words armour and horse, I didn't think to look up steed...

Comment: [That's a good thing, actually.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/are-duplicate-questions-a-bad-thing/5301) It will make the other question easier to search for since this one contains those words you mentioned and links to the other question.